# DAX Index and Match function?

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I'm trying to use function LOOKUPVALUE, but I have more than one ID and return error "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected"

For example:
I need to fill all lines in "Measure_id"

| Group_ID | ID | Desc | Measure_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 112233 | 0 | close | 12345 |
| 112233 | 12345 | open | 12345 |
| 112233 | 0 | close | 12345 |
| 223344 | 0 | close | 23456 |
| 223344 | 0 | close | 23456 |
| 223344 | 23456 | open | 23456 |
| 112233 | 12345 | open | 12345 |

Comment: What is your end goal? What does your data look like?

Answer (score 1):

`LOOKUPVALUE` is not compatible in DAX measure. You can replace it with following.

```
_return = 
VAR _1 =
    MAX ( 'fact'[Group_ID] )
VAR _2 =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'fact'[ID] ),
        ALL ( 'fact' ),
        FILTER ( VALUES ( 'fact'[Group_ID] ), 'fact'[Group_ID] = _1 )
    )
RETURN
    _2
```

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way of calculating this is by using `ALLEXCEPT()` in a measure like so:

```
Measure = 
CALCULATE ( 
    MAX ( 'Table'[ID] ) , 
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table' , 'Table'[Group_ID] )
)
```

This yields the same result as @smpa01 but is a much more performant measure, around 30-40% quicker on this data set, according to `DAX Studio` analysis.